# Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: post, javascript

заметил такую ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
onclick

```
<button id="save" type="button" onclick="save()" class="button on"><span class="icon icon158"></span><span class="label">Сохранить</span></button>
```

И post запрос:

```
function save() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save.php',
      data:{'data':'id'},
      success: function(data){
        $('#data').html('<br/>'+data);
    });
}
```

В чем проблема не пойму.

Comment: а функция save у вас есть вообще?

Comment: поправил код

Comment: **никогда не делайте onclick="function()" в разметке html, при использовании jQuery**

Comment: а как нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше так делайте:

HTML:

```
<button id="save" type="button" class="button on"><span class="icon icon158"></span><span class="label">Сохранить</span></button>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#save').click(save);
  function save() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save.php',
      data:{'data':'id'},  //вы тут посылаете строку 'id' это точно то что вы хотите ?
      success: function(data){
        $('#data').html('<br/>'+data);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: > //вы тут посылаете строку 'id' это точно то что вы хотите ?
нет:) это просто в качестве примера наисал.
важно было понять насчет js функции

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: `onclick="save();"`

Comment: даже onclick="save();return false" не помагает

Comment: сказать что-то наугад я вам вряд ли смогу, но так или иначе прислушайтесь к совету @eicto и откажитесь от использования onclick в скриптах. Возможно, это и вашу проблему также решит

Comment: спасибо:) буду разбираться